# Difference between yield * and yielding in a for..of loop?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

Given the following two pieces of code:

```
function * gen(g) {
  for (const value of g) {
    yield value;
  }
}
```

and

```
function * gen(g) {
  yield * g;
}
```

is there any difference in the behavior? As far as I can tell these are behaviorally identical. I'm having trouble seeing the value of the `yield *` syntax. It's more limiting than just iterating over the iterable in a for..of loop, and less obvious in what it does when reading it (in my opinion).

Comment: From what I see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*), it looks like they're pretty much the same except that `yield*` is an expression. The only other differences are that `yield*` is quicker to write, and I would guess it has been optimized somewhat.

Comment: @Anonymous: `yield ...` is an expression too.

Comment: @FelixKing But `for ... of` is a statement, so you can do `var x = yield* ...`, but not `var x = for ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [the ExploringJS explanation of the difference](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_generators.html#_yield-the-full-story), which is very exhaustive. The answer is typically, yes, they're equivalent, but there are some small differences. The most notable difference is that return values are forwarded by `yield *` but not by iterating and yielding.

Here's [an example](https://beta.observablehq.com/@tmcw/yield-vs-yield). The difference is minor.

Comment: Thanks, exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.